# CSV file generated using Apache POI showing unwanted characters when opened in Notepad

Tags: java, csv, apache-poi

I am trying to generate CSV file using apache poi.
The file will be accessed in MS excel as well as in notepad.

When I view the content of the file in MS excel, everything looks fine. However, when I open it in Notepad, it shows certain unwanted characters which fails the purpose to read it as comma separated file.

I have generate the file using Apache POI.

Below is my code:

```
 XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
                    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Data");


                        File file = new File("test.csv");

                        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

                        workbook.write(out);
```

I am unable to view the content in notepad.
I dont know if this is encoding issue or something else.

Below is the output:

```
¢(                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

    ¬ĖNĆ0E÷HüCä-JÜ²@5ķĒ*Q>ĄÄĘŖc[ii’ūB”j7±ĻÜ{2ńĶh²nm¶Ę»RČĄU^7/
ÅĒģ%ærZYļ @1__f q·ĆR4DįAJ¬h>ćŚĒVßĘ¹ŖZØ9ČŪĮąNVŽ8Ź©ÓćŃŌji){^óć-I"{Üv^„P!XS)bR¹rśK¾s(ø3Õ`cŽ0½ŻĪß»¾7M4²©ōŖZĘk+æ|\|zæ(ōPśŗ6h_-[@!ŅŲ Pk“­2nĻ}Ä?£LĖšĀ
```

How can I resolve this?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you show us a couple of lines from the output?  Off the top of my head, this could be a line ending issue.

Comment: Hi @Tim Biegeleisen, I have updated the question with the output. Please see if this is of some help.

Comment: I don't think POI works this way, namely it can't just output an Excel workbook as CSV.

Comment: All right, Got your point. That means if I am renaming the extension of file to CSV instead of XLS, it wont change the encoding to that of CSV. Thanks Tim,. I will try to do it the other way..

Comment: Precisely...changing the extension won't change what's in the file, which is Excel workbook stuff.  But, I think you can use POI and iterate over the worksheet to generate your own CSV.